# c++ How to stop all functions when a certain parameter is met

Tags: c++, multithreading

in c++ How can I stop or pause all other functions while this condition is met

```
else if (packet[0] == 0x5)
{

}
```

Basically I have a separate void function running a constant loop however if packet[0] ==0x5 i need it to stop all other threads (or pause)

Please
and 
thanks
Ant

Comment: you need to provide more information. What multithreading system do you use? posix? boost? win32? c++11? How are the other threads started?

Comment: Bigger question: why do you want to stop all your threads? how do you communicate with your threads? if you have them all listening to some IPC then introduce a stop IPC call and send it to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

In 'stdlib.h' there is a function **exit(int Status_Code)** which terminates execution of whole program. You should call **exit(1)** .

If you want only terminate that function just use return. e.g.

```
if(condition_met)
{
 return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a direct way to stop or pause other threads (other then stopping the entire program by `exit(0)`). The only approach I'm aware of is a cooperative way where the threads which need to stop or pause are notified in some way and proactively act upon this notification. How the notification would look exactly depends largely on your system. One approach could be an atomic flag indicating that there is a need to act. If your threads supporting messaging, sending each one a message is probably more lightweight.

Comment: What about blocking on a mutex?

Comment: @nishantjr: if there are many threads locking a mutex seems like a contention point. You'd still have all the synchronization setting an atomic variable has (probably more) and you may also reduce concurrency.

Comment: If you want all your threads to block there is nothing wrong with blocking on a mutex. Making them wait faster in a busy loop on an atomic uselessly burns CPU-cycles for no gain. Also depending on the library used you can keep a list of threads and then just make them all sleep. Some also support waiting on a signal or event.

Comment: @nwp: My understanding of the question is that the other threads are normally busy. To make them stop they'll need to receive some indication to stop. Using a mutex for this indication seems fairly expensive. Once the notification is received it seems the threads should "stop" (which I read as the tread should terminate) or pause. For pausing I agree that a mutex is better than spinning but I would not use it as the only communication.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put all those function calls into a thread, and when your realise you need to stop those functions, kill the thread

Comment: Killing threads is evil, it will not call destructors and for example keep a mutex locked and block all other threads indefinitely.

Comment: True. What I meant was thread.stop(), kill would be ambigous, thanks nwp